# How do I extract strings with three forward slashes?

Tags: python, string, list

I want to print out the items with three forward slashes as in my desired output.

Everything I try to find is extracting the data in between the slashes or just finding the ones with a slash.

```
data = ['int', '3/1/2/8', '4/2/1', '5/6/9/2',
    '4/1', '9/2/1', '1/4/8/6', 'prod', ]
for info in data:
    if '%d/%d/%d/%d' in info:
        print(info)
```

Desired outcome:

```
 3/1/2/8
 5/6/9/2
 1/4/8/6
```

Comment: Try `info.count('/') == 3`?

Comment: perfect.  thanks a bunch.  so easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .count() as follows:

```
data = ['int', '3/1/2/8', '4/2/1', '5/6/9/2',
    '4/1', '9/2/1', '1/4/8/6', 'prod', ]
for info in data:
    if info.count('/') == 3:
        print(info)
```

Answer (score 2):

A regular expression can help:

```
import re

out=[]
data=['int', '3/1/2/8', '4/2/1', '5/6/9/2','4/1', '9/2/1', '1/4/8/6', 'prod' ]

for i in data:
    if(re.match(".*/.*/.*/.*",i)):
        out.append(i)

print(out)
```

Output from this:

```
['3/1/2/8', '5/6/9/2', '1/4/8/6']
```

Answer (score 0):

You have just to make a function that checks if there is 4 /

```
for i in data:
    if len(i.split("/")) == 4:
        print(i)
```